# MySQL: multi-row update with one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with 3,000+ rows fomrated like this

```
$COUNTS = array(
1=>5,
2=>22,
3=>120,
4=>0,
....
);
```

where the key represents an ID and value is the calculated COUNT...

I need to update all the rows in my table with these new values (with php)...

so right now I am updating them one by one
(simplified) like

```
foreach($COUNTS as $id=>$count){
mysql_query("UPDATE categories SET count=$count WHERE id=$id");
}
```

I would need to make 3,000+ queries, to make a simple update....

can this be done in one query or any other less resource consuming way? maybe generating a csv file and updating on the fly or something?

Comment: You could try using XML see the section "Reading XML with XML::Parser" in [Using XML with MySQL](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/mysql-xml.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
UPDATE categories c
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT 1 as id, 23 as `cnt`
   UNION
   SELECT 2 as id, 25 as `cnt`
   -- UNION  etc
)a
ON  c.id = a.id
SET c.`count` = a.cnt
```

Comment: The result is about the same...It still needs about 9s to complete.

Comment: I think it should be a bit better, at least you execute 1 query, not 3k

Comment: Yes, a bit, about 3% improve... I need at least 70% improve

Comment: What is the most time consuming part? Query execution or iterating through an array? If you have an index on `id` and no index on `count`, the query by itself should be executing quite fast.

Comment: Ok, nvm, it is something else, that is time consuming I am triggering afterwards, sorry..

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might've figured this out but a couple of recommendations anyway. If you're doing a large update (especially one time or rarely), make sure any triggers are disabled (if not necessary) as well as indexes. Indexes don't seem to be the issue in your case though.

You can certainly leave your query in a loop. 9s for 3000 records seems high but depending on what else is going on, that might be ok.

You can also write the data into a file and then bulk insert the file into a new table via

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html for reference. You will then have to join the two tables for updates. You'd have to deal with file IO in this case and another db connection so not sure how much savings you'll get.

Another option is to create a prepared statement and bind parameters to it. That should run a bit quicker too. Check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php for more info